Set new state in object in array
I have a problem with updating my object in array.
const [list, setList] = useState([]);

const changeRecordIndex = list.findIndex(
  (recordItem) => recordItem.id === recordID
);

I create a new array, copy the object which I need and then change one parameter of the object. It looks like great! But in this case I have a problem with final array - I have 2 similar objects with different parameters which I'm trying to change.
setList([
  ...list,
  { ...list[changeRecordIndex], taskText: liItem.innerText }
]);

In this case everything is ok
const newArr = [...list];
newArr[changeRecordIndex] = {
  ...newArr[changeRecordIndex],
  taskText: liItem.innerText
};
setList(newArr);

What's wrong with first case?

Use Array.map() to iterate the state, and when you encounter the item you want to update, return a new item. For the rest just return the existing item. Array.map() also returns a new array, so you're shallow cloning the array, and the changed item at once.
In addition, when you want to update the previous state instead of replacing it, pass an updater function when you're setting the state. The updater function is called with the previous state.
setList(prevList => prevList.map(recordItem => 
  recordItem.id === recordID
  ? { ...recordItem, taskText: liItem.innerText }
  : recordItem
));

A newer option is to use Array.toSpliced(), which can remove/add items at a specific index:
setList(prevList => {
  const changeRecordIndex = list.findIndex(
    recordItem => recordItem.id === recordID
  );
  
  return prevList.toSpliced(changeRecordIndex, 1, {
    ...prevList[changeRecordIndex], 
    taskText: liItem.innerText 
  });
});


As Andy said above, the issue with your code is that you're not removing the old object from the array.
Another alternative (more concise, in my opinion) would be to use the Array's toSpliced() method, like so:
    const newRecord = { ...list[changeRecordIndex], taskText: liItem.innerText };

    const newArr = list.toSpliced(changeRecordIndex, 1, newRecord);

    setList(newArr);

P.S.: make sure to guard against findIndex()'s possible negative result (-1)
    if(changeRecordIndex < 0) {
        // "fail fast" here
    }
    // else, update your state


The issue is that the code spreads the objects, not the properties, therefore it does not do the intent.
Spread operator spreads objects when used it with an array of objects. This is unlike when it is used with an object. It is to note that when spread operator is used with an object, it spreads the properties, and the properties with same name will overwrite with the latest value.
Explaining the failing code
The first or failing set of statements is equivalent to the below code.
For brevity, it uses an array of Numbers instead of an array of objects.
The statement basically adds a new value into the array which may be self-explanatory. The same would happen in case of an array of objects as well.
const copyOflist1 = [1, 2, 3]; // copy of the orginal array
const newList1 = [...copyOflist1, 3];
console.log(newList1); // [ 1, 2, 3, 3 ]

The passing code
The second or passing set of statements is equivalent to the below code.
What it does may also be self-explanatory, it changes the value of the index 2.
The same would happen in case of an array of objects as well. Therefore it does the intent.
const copyOflist2 = [1, 2, 3]; // copy of the orginal array
const indexOfTheValue3 = 2;
copyOflist2[indexOfTheValue3] = 4;
console.log(copyOflist2); // [ 1, 2, 4 ]

The possible confusion
The possible confusion behind the failing code may with the object spread operation. In this case the below statement does the intent, since the spread operator spreads the actual properties of the object.
Therefore the property c gets correctly overwritten by the new value.
However, in the original code, it spreads the objects, not the properties.
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const newObject = { ...obj, c: 4 };
console.log(newObject); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 }

